# How to get image to hide and become visible again with album art? android xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having trouble figure out how to hide certain images within a group, I currently use this group setup

```
 <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="88.0px" android:layout_height="95.0px"  >
    <ImageView android:layout_width="67.0px" android:layout_height="75.0px" android:src="@drawable/coverart" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0px" android:layout_marginTop="10.0px" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <ImageButton android:id="@id/albumArt" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="67.0px" android:layout_height="75.0px" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0px" android:layout_marginTop="10.0px" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />
    <ImageView android:layout_width="88.0px" android:layout_height="95.0px" android:src="@drawable/peel" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now this hides the album art when paused, but I can't figure out how to hide the overlay. Everything I try just constantly hides the whole group. I know there must be a way to hide the whole group then bring it back on play like the actual album art does.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: use framelayout to do the complete operations....better you ignore static values..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try hiding your entire layout instead of hiding only the elements. Hide your layout when paused and bring it back when you want.

```
 <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="88.0px" android:layout_height="95.0px"  android:visibility="gone">
<ImageView android:layout_width="67.0px" android:layout_height="75.0px" android:src="@drawable/coverart" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0px" android:layout_marginTop="10.0px" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
<ImageButton android:id="@id/albumArt"  android:layout_width="67.0px" android:layout_height="75.0px" android:layout_marginLeft="16.0px" android:layout_marginTop="10.0px" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:adjustViewBounds="true"  />
<ImageView android:layout_width="88.0px" android:layout_height="95.0px" android:src="@drawable/peel" android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: I tried that, but the whole layout remains hidden and doesn't appear on playback :( That was the first thing I tried

Comment: So again on playback you have to change its visibility from "gone" to "visible". did you do this

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by that? Did I change the visibility on the album art back to visible? If so, yes. If theres something else I needed to change, no.